# How to use a select to go to the Show action of another controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, routes

I'm trying to do something I thought easy and natural but I'm struggling..

On the homepage of my website, I want a select containing a list of users. After selecting a user and clicking on a button, it should go to the show action of the User controller page.

I searched and found differents answers that I don't find very elegant:

- using AJAX http://www.mail-archive.com/rubyonrails-talk@googlegroups.com/msg36368.html
- using an observe_field to modify the url in the html

Is there a better way doing this?

What would be the best way?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this with jQuery...or just plain old javascript.

```
$("#button_id").click(function(){
  window.location = '/users/' + $("#select_list_id").children("option:selected").val();
});
```

That should add an onclick method to the button and then forward you to '/user/12345'.

You could do the same thing in plain javascript if you aren't using jquery, but it's a little more involved.

```
<script type="javascript">
  function goToUsersPage() {
    list = document.getElementById('select_list_id')
    window.location = '/users' + list.options[selectedIndex].value;
  }
</script>
```

Then you need to add the function call to the onclick method of your button.

```
<input type='button' onclick='goToUsersPage();' value='Go!'/>
```

Comment: I would use the change() function, just my $0.02

Comment: change() if you attach the event to the select list, click if you attach it to a button the user has to click to initiate the page jump.  I hate it when a drop down list automatically takes me somewhere...i seem to mis-click in the list a lot and i end up waiting 2 or 3 page loads until I click the right item.  If there was a button I wouldn't have to wait for the page reloads.

Comment: yeah I would suggest using change()

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using javascript you could just make the select and button a form and have an action in the controller that takes the user id and redirects to the user's page.

Something like:

```
def user_form
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to(@user) }
  end
end
```